# Save PDF to file

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am working on a Windows Store app for Windows 8.1, and I can't find anything that addresses what I need to do. I am trying to save an image of a pdf page to my local app data storage. I have the following:

```
private async void GetFirstPage()
    {
        // Retrieve file from FutureAccessList
        StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(token);

        // Truncate last 4 chars; ex: '.pdf'
        FileName = file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - 4);

        // Get access to pdf functionality from file
        PdfDocument doc = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);

        // Get a copy of the first page
        PdfPage page = doc.GetPage(0);

        // Below could be used to tweak render options for optimizations later
        //PdfPageRenderOptions options = new PdfPageRenderOptions();

        // Render the first page to the BitmapImage
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await page.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);

        // Common code
        Cover.SetSource(stream);

        // Convert the active BitmapImage Cover to a storage file to be stored locally
        // ???

    }
```

The variable, Cover, is a BitmapImage that is bound in XAML to display the image to the user. I want to save this image to my local app data so that I don't have to re-render it through the PDF library every time my app opens! The problem is I can't save anything in a Windows Store app from a stream unless it is text to my knowledge, (no filestream or fileoutputstreams for me), and Cover's URI source is null, since it was sourced from a stream, making it difficult to get my BitmapImage, Cover, to a StorageFile for proper Windows Store saving.

Everything works for me currently, I'm just upset about re-rendering the pdf page to my bitmapimage from scratch every time my app opens. Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the image from the PdfPage directly rather than from the BitmapImage since you can't get the data out of the BitmapImage. The PdfPage.RenderToStreamAsync already encodes the stream as a bitmap so you don't need to do any manipulation beyond sending it to the file. This is essentially the same as what you are doing to save to the InMemoryRandomAccessStream, except to a file based stream:

```
//We need a StorageFile to save into.
StorageFile saveFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("safedPdf.png",CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

using (var saveStream = await saveFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    await page.RenderToStreamAsync(saveStream);
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, and it really makes sense now! I must be dense >.< Thank you so much :)